# input arguments from txt files in C programs

Tags: c, file, input, arguments

i made an program which can take multiple arguments. Unfortunately when it comes to big numbers it is quite impractical to input them manually. SO the question is. Can i use .txt file which would contain all arguments and load them from file while starting my program? I would be grateful for help.

Comment: There's no way of setting `argv`/`argc` from the contents of a file, not automatically anyway. You have to read the file and parse the arguments in it into your own `argc`/`argv`-style variables.

Comment: What´s the difference between putting the numbers manually in a text file and adding them manually to your program call?

Comment: You could add them, with your program call, to a batch file instead (if you think putting it in a file is more practical), maybe?

Comment: Use pipe `|` if you are on UNIX machine.
Eg: `echo args.txt | ./myfile`

Comment: i got core dumped error.hmmm why i got this error when using arg from file, but when i put them manually everything is ok? http://pastebin.com/grKRv85Q

Comment: I want to use this arguments from txt file and put them in argc/argv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type your data (input manually), consider substitution of input stream while running program as

```
      Program <input.txt
```

In that case input.txt file have to contain all data that you type manually before. No rewriting and rebuilding code are needed.

**EDIT:**

To add command line arguments run program from scrip such as

```
     # this is runprog script
     Program arg1 arg2 arg3
```

when you run `runprog` it runs `Program` and `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3` become argv (argc is counted automatically)

Comment: i want this arguments to be put in argv... :)